# Cannot import statsmodels.formula.api

Tags: python, statsmodels

Whenever i am trying to import statsmodels.formula.api as smf i get the following error.

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-257-268d740a5877>", line 1, in <module>
   import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

File "C:\Users\ldresl\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
    packages\statsmodels\formula\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  from statsmodels import PytestTester

 ImportError: cannot import name 'PytestTester'
```

Comment: Do you have pytest installed? It looks like it's a runtime requirement.

Comment: I have pytest install :(

Comment: I met the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

You will have to update the package `pytest` and restart your kernel:

```py
pip install pytest --upgrade
```

I had this problem importing `statsmodels` in a Jupyter notebook (Anaconda distribution). If you run on the same set-up, you can [update a package in Anaconda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#updating-packages) like so:

```py
conda update pytest
```

Do not forget to restart the kernel in the top navigation of your notebook afterwards. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me,

1. pip install statsmodels --upgrade
2. pip install pytest --upgrade

> > Restart Kernel